# How to programatticaly refresh Excel data dynamically from sharepoint c#

Tags: c#, excel, sharepoint, refresh

I have an Excel sheet which is connected to Sharepoint and while clicking Data->RefreshAll Data updates in Excel dynamically after entering credentials,login username and password.I have to set up a c# application which mimics the functionality of RefreshAll Button in which program should Accept credential entry via code with out any user interaction.

C# Program to Refresh Sharepoint Excel Sheet

Comment: You mean like the [Workbook.RefreshAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.refreshall) method?

Comment: Yeh.But while trying to  do RefreshAll in Excel ,It asks login username & password .May I know How to include credentials in code also?

Comment: [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dilkushp/2014/09/24/refreshing-excel-files-which-has-data-sources-not-supported-by-powerbi/) could be interesting. He opens a connection to the sharepoint where the credentials are entered, fetches the workbook and refreshes it. I think thats your possible workaround.

Comment: Is there any way to giving credentials in background code , instead of interactive screen while refresh take place from c# code..Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in Advance